# PHP error after laravel installation

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to use laravel for my php project. I use WampServer2.2 (php 5.3.8 and Apache 2.2.21) on Windows 8.1. But after all kind of installation I tried (via composer or downloading the zip), when I get to the public folder in my browser I get PHP errors as  :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\spi\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php on line 411
```

or

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\wamp\www\spi\laravel-master\bootstrap\compiled.php on line 506
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You say that your php version is 5.3.8 and [the laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#server-requirements) say that 5.4 is required. The latest version(2.5) of WampServer comes with php 5.5.

Comment: No the  docs says that the requirment are : php >=5.3.7  and MCrypt PHP Extension. I got php 5.3.8  http://laravel.com/docs/installation#server-requirements

Comment: What version are you downloading? Github and Composer provide the latest version(4.2) which requires PHP >= 5.4.

Comment: @benmuriel Your own link says **PHP >= 5.4** :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Actually the version is not included in the url. I wanted to check the requirements for previous versions and the url stayed the same, even though the requirements were different. :)

Comment: You're both right. The link says what's required for whatever version you're browsing (not in the url, cookie based) ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. upgrade PHP to PHP 5.6
2. You can use this command for local development server

   php artisan serve